# InfluxDB v2 Setup C#

Tags: c#, influxdb, influxdb-2

Is there a way to setup InfluxDB v2.7 using the c# client (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-csharp/tree/master) or in C# program somehow

something like what the /api/v2/setup API would do

Also, to clarify

it is okay to create another admin account, then delete the one i made during the setup?
will this create some kind of problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just assume we cant, since the library needs us to authenticate to make a connection. I'm just going to use the API for the setup and the rest using the library.

Also wont be deleting the account, instead I'll just change the password of the current user